# How to convert snapshot in typescript code for firebase cloud functions into string to use for notification?

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I have the bellow code for cloud functions which is meant to, on creation of a new follower, send a notification to the user. The issue is that I dont know how to convert the snap into a string so that I can fix the error message included bellow.

```
 function sendNewFollowNotificationFunc(uuid: string, newFollower: string) {
  // const userRef = admin.database().ref('PeopleWhoFollowMe').child(uuid)
  // const fetchAndUpdate = userRef.once('value')
  console.log('User to send notification', uuid);

  admin.database().ref(`UsersFireTokens`).child(uuid).child("token").once('value')
  .then(snap => {
    const token = snap.val//I dont know how, from here I should be handling this inorder to get the value at this location which is the token
    // This registration token comes from the client FCM SDKs.
    var registrationToken = token;

    var message = {
      data: {
        text: 'This is a test',
        time: '2:45'
      },
      token: registrationToken
    };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    admin.messaging().send(message)//error here
      .then((response) => {
        // Response is a message ID string.
        console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error sending message:', error);
      });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error in catch: "+error)
    response.status(500).send(error)
  })
```

The problem is I am getting many errors such as:

> Argument of type '{ data: { text: string; time: string; }; token: string | null; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Message'.
>     Type '{ data: { text: string; time: string; }; token: string | null; }' is not assignable to type 'TokenMessage'.
>       Types of property 'token' are incompatible.
>         Type 'string | null' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>           *Type 'null*' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2345)

**What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?**

### **Update:**

This is my code:

```
function sendNewFollowNotificationFunc(uuid: string, newFollower: string) {
  // const userRef = admin.database().ref('PeopleWhoFollowMe').child(uuid)
  // const fetchAndUpdate = userRef.once('value')
  console.log('User to send notification', uuid);

  admin.database().ref(`UsersFireTokens`).child(uuid).child("token").once('value')
  .then(snap => {
    //What should I be doing here and how?
console.log('token value', snap.val);//doing this returns a strange function thing in the logs

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("Error in catch: "+error)
    response.status(500).send(error)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The long and convoluted tsc message tells you that your `message` variable has the type:

`{ data: { text: string; time: string; }; token: string | null; }`

but `send` expects a `TokenMessage`. It is impossible to know all about the `TokenMessage` type from your code, but it appears that it contains a `token` field of type `string`. Your `message`, on the other hand, has a `token` field with type `string | null`. Therefore, types not match: your `message` may not have a `token`, while `send` expects something that is guaranteed to have a `token` string.

> What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

You need to call `send` with some value that complies with the `TokenMessage` type.

To do so, one way is to cast `message` to `tokenMessage`:

```
 admin.messaging().send(message as Message)
```

(**tldr: the above like will probably fix your issue**)

Sometimes, two types are too incompatibles to be casted. In such cases, you cannot force it as in the above line. You can still cast to `any` and then to your desired type:

`admin.messaging().send(message as any as Message)`

---

Said so, this is not always that you should do:

Typescript is complaining about `message` maybe not having a `token`. That's neat. usually, you can avoid those tsc warnings by making assertions over your variables:

```
function getToken(): string | null {
    return 'f00';
}

function test(s: string) { 

}

const t = getToken();

test(t); // error

if (t) {
    test(t); // safe, no error
    // this is great because force you to handle potential null stuff at developing time
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work with object fields:

```
function getToken(): string | null {
    return 'f00';
}

interface Message{
    token: string;
}

function send(m: Message) { 

}

const t = getToken();

const message = {
    token: t,
}

send(message); // error

if (t) {
    send(message); // error
}

if (message.token) { 
    send(message); // still an error, this puzzles me a lot. At this point tsc should now that message complies with Message. There is something I don't have clear at this point.
}

send(message as Message); // valid
```

In general, it is better an safer to check for nulls via `if` blocks rather than casting types manually. But sometimes there is no other way around.

Comment: I see. So null checks inside `if` clauses does not read inside object properties. Let me edit this again